# Android: Service value to a BroacastReceiver

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

I am a beginner and already read posts about the service and broadcastreceiver components.
Still I do not really now, what to do here.
I have a Service (Class: ExampleService) that always changes a variable k:

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

```
while (k < 1000) {

    if(forward==true){
        k++;
    }else{
    k--;    
    }


    synchronized (this) {

        try {

            wait(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

k = 0;
this.stopSelf();

}

public long getInt(){
    return k;
}
```

and my BroadcastReceiver:

```
BroadcastReceiver broadi=new BroadcastReceiver(){

@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ExampleIntentService se=new ExampleIntentService();

            text.setText("Count:"+String.valueOf(se.getInt()));
}

};
```

So I create an object of the service and try to get that value with my 'getInt()' method.
It always returns 0 and I dont know why.
Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call

```
ExampleIntentService se=new ExampleIntentService();
```

you are creating a new istance of that class, you are not referring to the running instance of the service. I think you have 2 chances:

- make `k` and its getter method static. making it static `k` will not become instance dependent and you can read its value by calling

  ExampleIntentService.getInt();
- send a broadcast, that can be received by your broadcast receiver,every time you change `k`  but i think that is to much work by the moment that you could send 10 broadcast in a second for 100 seconds